# openJdk8 build in Windows: Build jdk error

Tags: java, java-8, windows-7-x64

Am trying to build openJDK8 in windows 64-bit. Following https://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2012/09/building-openjdk-on-windows.html for building.

OS: Windows 7-64-bit

Installed Cygwin, Visual studio 2013, Microsoft SDK, Ant and set all the paths in environment variable.

Built make and freetype 64-bit. Using jdk7 from Oracle as boot-jdk. configure was success. Then when i given

```
make clean images

Getting build error in jdk:

d:\Preethi\openjdk8\jdk\src\share\classes\java\io\PrintStream.java:31: error: cannot access IllegalCharsetNameException
import java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException;
                       ^
  bad source file: d:\Preethi\openjdk8\build\windows-x86_64-normal-server-release\jdk\gensrc\java\nio\charset\IllegalCharsetNameException.java
    file does not contain class java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
d:\Preethi\openjdk8\jdk\src\share\classes\java\io\ObjectOutputStream.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
import static java.io.ObjectStreamClass.processQueue;
^
  symbol:   static processQueue
  location: class
d:\Preethi\openjdk8\jdk\src\share\classes\java\io\ObjectInputStream.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
import static java.io.ObjectStreamClass.processQueue;
^
  symbol:   static processQueue
  location: class
d:\Preethi\openjdk8\jdk\src\share\classes\java\lang\annotation\Retention.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
                          ^
  symbol:   method value()
  location: @interface Retention
d:\Preethi\openjdk8\jdk\src\share\classes\java\lang\SuppressWarnings.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
         ^
  symbol: variable TYPE
d:\Preethi\openjdk8\jdk\src\share\classes\java\lang\SuppressWarnings.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
               ^
  symbol: variable FIELD
d:\Preethi\openjdk8\jdk\src\share\classes\java\lang\SuppressWarnings.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
                      ^
  symbol: variable METHOD
d:\Preethi\openjdk8\jdk\src\share\classes\java\lang\SuppressWarnings.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
                              ^
  symbol: variable PARAMETER
d:\Preethi\openjdk8\jdk\src\share\classes\java\lang\SuppressWarnings.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
                                         ^
  symbol: variable CONSTRUCTOR
d:\Preethi\openjdk8\jdk\src\share\classes\java\lang\SuppressWarnings.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
                                                      ^
  symbol: variable LOCAL_VARIABLE
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute kind <error> (class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute$Error)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:180)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitMethodDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1066)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:778)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitClassDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1042)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$1.run(TypeAnnotations.java:127)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:152)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.JavadocEnter.main(JavadocEnter.java:78)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.JavadocTool.getRootDocImpl(JavadocTool.java:186)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:346)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:219)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:205)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:64)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:54)
javadoc: error - fatal error
makegensrc/GensrcSwing.gmk:77: recipe for target `/cygdrive/d/Preethi/openjdk8/build/windows-x86_64-normal-server-release/jdk/gensrc_no_srczip/_the.generated_be
aninfo' failed[2]: *** [/cygdrive/d/Preethi/openjdk8/build/windows-x86_64-normal-server-release/jdk/gensrc_no_srczip/_the.generated_beaninfo] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
BuildJdk.gmk:55: recipe for target `gensrc-only' failedmake[1]: *** [gensrc-only] Error 2

/cygdrive/d/Preethi/openjdk8//make/Main.gmk:116: recipe for target `jdk-only' failed
make: *** [jdk-only] Error 2
```

can somebody point-out the issue?
boot-jdk : java version "1.7.0_80" downloaded from Oracle. That blog is meant for openjdk 7 only. But i tried the same steps for building openjdk8 2 years back and it got success.

Comment: What's your boot JDK? Also note that blog post is about building JDK7, though I'm not sure, I think building process has changed a bit in JDK8.

Comment: I have done all the setup for building openjdk 8 in different windows system. Used jdk1.8.0_65 as bootjdk. I can able to successfully build the openjdk.